# How can I create a wordpress post in another wordpress site using their REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I want to create and update a wordpress post from one site which would automatically post to another wordpress site. I've tried playing around with the REST API in wordpres 4.7+ but I keep getting the following message

```
{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Any thoughts on how I can tackle this?

Thanks

Comment: Which role does the user doing the creation have?

Comment: Maybe this will be of interest: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rest-cannot-create-error/

Comment: @cjs1978 I looked at that but that didn't help at all. I think the problem is that I might not be using the right authentication method hence the 401 HTTP code. I'm using Basic authentication. Not sure if there's an easier route to achieve what i'm trying to get

Answer (score 0):

I can create a post from localhost into live wordpress blog with basic authentication. So I think you can post remotely a wordpress blog from another wordpress website. I use php file_get_contents and cURL , both are working.
You may try this method bellow 
http://www.wpsaga.info/wp-rest-api-create-post-with-php-curl/

Comment: I tried this method but still didn't work for me. I get the same error I was getting before.

Comment: have you installed and activating Basic Auth Master Plugin from here  https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth ?